# Get module name and its all dependencies list in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get `module name` and `all dependencies list` that is `injected` in `application module`.

Like :

```
var app = angular.module( 'wp', ['ngRoute', 'abc', 'xyz'] );
```

So from this i want to get all this component list like `wp,ngRoute,abc,xyz`

Using `Angular JS.`

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In angular js, you can use the **`requires`** array to get all the dependency modules of the main module.

**The syntax of the module declaration:**

`angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);`

The second parameter, the dependencies in an array named requires.

**So, app.requires gives you the required result.**

Here is an example:

```
var app = angular.module('App', [
    'ngRoute',
    'appServices',
    'toaster',
    'ngValidate',
    'uiGmapgoogle-maps',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'offClick'
]);
```

**`console.log(app.requires);`**

gives you,

```
Array[8] 

[
"ngRoute",
"appServices",
"toaster",
"ngValidate",
"uiGmapgoogle-maps",
"ngSanitize",
"ngFileUpload",
"offClick"
]
```

**Update:**

**1)** If you don't have a variable for your module, you can use,

**`angular.module('App').requires`**

**2)** If you don't know the module name at all, then you can use,

**`angular.module($rootElement.attr('ng-app')).requires;`**

for this you should add `$rootElement` as dependency

Eg:

```
.run(["$rootScope","$rootElement",function($rootScope,$rootElement){

   console.log(angular.module('App').requires);

   console.log(angular.module($rootElement.attr('ng-app')).requires);

}]);
```

**3)** Even if you dont have the code with you you can simply try, 
`$("[ng-app]").attr('ng-app')` if you have jquery to get the module name.

**`angular.module($("[ng-app]").attr('ng-app')).requires;`**

Comment: Suppose what if i dont have this variable name `app` then??

Comment: then you can use,`console.log(angular.module('App').requires);`

Comment: @Sravan...usefull info but i want to know one thing as in the asked question .....if i dont know the module name also then how can we achive this ?

Comment: you mean you even don't know the name of the module declared? is it?

Comment: for this, you can use,
`(angular.module($rootElement.attr('ng-app')).requires)`, need to add `$rootElement` as a dependency.

Comment: @Sravan...Yes...i'm creating one plugins in angularjs and for front user i want to get default module name so that i can apply my custom functionality on this module...i have try to get that but dont get it anything..so i try it by other by like if i get module name and all dependices list then i can create that angular.module same like front user has done..

Comment: even if you dont have the code with you you can simply try,
`$("[ng-app]").attr('ng-app')` if you have jquuery to get the module name

Comment: @Sravan..your third answer is not working and for second answer firstly i dont know module name so on what parameter or variable name i should apply `.run` method?

Comment: @Sravan too much bro.....we are here to share not for score or points......any way here is my up for u

Comment: not like that bro, one will see an answer only if it have a vote, I have the habit of skipping the answers that does not have vote. you can remove your vote if this answer gets accepted.

Comment: @Sravan let me explain you what i want to do..ok??..user have used angular js in his website and already defined its angular.module()  variable name suppose its named as `app` so now i'm creating external plugins and now i want to add my custom plugin functionality for user in his website so i must need to apply my functionality on variable that user have defined in his main app.js...ok?? so i want to variable name..hope you got it...:)

Comment: so for example, if you have `var app = angular.module( 'wp', ['ngRoute', 'abc', 'xyz'] );` you need `app` from it or `wp`?

Comment: I need `app` then only i can apply my functionality on this variable like `app.whaterver`

Comment: do you know the module name?

Comment: No ..l dont know...please check this..and also check both js file...http://plnkr.co/edit/wZ9D6Z16i2C24MOatpbQ?p=info

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129001/discussion-between-sravan-and-jivani-jaydeep).